# Each song in an Audio Player can change the Background's Color

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio, background

I was wondering if the following is possible:

I have a page with an audio player. Whenever a song changes automatically or someone clicks on a song in the tracklist, I want to make this song change the colors of the background. The background is gradient animation.

1. For instance, *Song 01* will have a class *"sad,"* and will change the background with darker colors;
2. *Song 02* will be *"happy,"* and will change the background with brighter colors.

I will have many different color palettes, but I also want to assign the songs with a specific color palettes (not randomize it).

So far, the example below is what I have. In this JSFiddle demo, I can change the background on click, but unfortunately it doesn't work when a song ends and the next one automatically plays.

http://jsfiddle.net/georgeyanakiev/ca9pmv4L/3/

```
<a href="#" onclick="bgFrame.className='happy'" data-src="SONG URL">SONG TITLE</a>

.happy { background: linear-gradient(270deg, #3e23ff, #3cff3c, #ff1962, #2dafe6); background-size: 600% 600%; -webkit-animation: Gradient 60s ease infinite; -moz-animation: Gradient 60s ease infinite; animation: Gradient 60s ease infinite; }
```

I'd appreciate some help and suggestions!

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it in JavaScript as we need to find out when the current song changes and when it happens, we need to do something equivalent to your `onclick="bgFrame.className='happy'"`

You can achieve that by doing ssomething like this :

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var bgFrame = document.getElementById('bgFrame');

audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
    var playing = document.querySelector('li.playing');
    var playingSong = playing.querySelector('a');
    eval(playingSong.getAttribute('onclick'));
});
```

We are adding a event listener which checks when the current song is `ended` and when it gets triggered, it does the following :

1. Find *playing* list item.
2. Find the `a` tag inside that list item.
3. Finds the `onclick` attribute of that `a` tag and then calls `eval` on that which essentially runs that code and you get the effect.

Here is updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca9pmv4L/4/)

Comment: Thank you, Patel! You are my hero. One more question: is it possible to make a smooth fade transition between the background color changes?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without making basic changes in your code as you've `linear-gradient` set in css classes. You can, in fact, make it a bit easier and straightforward if you're willing to use jQuery.

Comment: Great, I'd use jQuery if needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad that I could help. You might want to consider upvoting and [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) then? :)